# fakeroot-ng with debootstrap variant fakechroot hangs on makedev

Tags: debootstrap, fakechroot, fakeroot

So I am trying to bootstrap a Ubuntu as unprivileged user on Ubuntu. The little script I am using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DEBARCHIVE_URL="http://localhost:3142/de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/"
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
        fakeroot-ng -f -l"$(pwd)/fakeroot-ng.log" -p"$(pwd)/fakeroot-ng.state" \
        fakechroot \
        debootstrap \
                --keep-debootstrap-dir \
                --exclude=dhcp3-common,dhcp3-client,laptop-detect,tasksel,tasksel-data \
                --variant=fakechroot \
                --arch=amd64 \
                $(lsb_release -sc) "${1:-$(pwd)/build_chroot}" ${DEBARCHIVE_URL}
```

The gist is, that `debootstrap` hangs at the following operation:

```
I: Configuring makedev...
```

In `htop` (but not in `pstree`) I can see that the blocking command is:

```
mknod mem- c 1 1
```

invoked by:

```
/bin/sh - /sbin/MAKEDEV std consoleonly fd
```

invoked by:

```
/bin/sh -e /var/lib/dpkg/info/makedev.postinst configure
```

which itself is invoked by `dpkg`.

Summary (in order of invocation):

```
/bin/sh -e /var/lib/dpkg/info/makedev.postinst configure
    /bin/sh - /sbin/MAKEDEV std consoleonly fd
        mknod mem- c 1 1
```

This is flabbergasting, since I am giving `--variant=fakechroot` and therefore should expect to have no trouble with potentially privileged commands.

What am I doing wrong or how else would I go about bootstrapping a `chroot` environment for later use with `fakeroot fakechroot chroot ...`?

---

Here's the relevant tail of the `fakeroot` log file:

```
4937: Called mknod(NONE)
mknod: 4937 tried to create character device, turn to regular file
mknod: 4937 mode 401
4502: Calling syscall 5 redirected from open
4937: Called mknod(RETURN)
mknod: 4937 call failed with error Permission denied
4502: Called syscall 5, redirected from open
open: 4502 map for dev 5 inode 1029 already exists - doing nothing
process 4937 orig_sc=133 actual sc=79 state=RETURN
```

Comment: When in doubt consult the sources http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/d-i/debootstrap.git/tree/debootstrap

Comment: @Braiam: okay, after your remark I did. There seems to be no special handling for `fakechroot`. What am I missing? Are you trying to point out that I stumbled over a defect in `debootstrap`?